# CSS Layout 2-Column fixed-fluid

Tags: html, css, layout

I was wondering if anyone here had a fairly simple tutorial for the following 2 column css layout.
A left fixed column and a fluid content column, with a header and footer and equal column heights.

Comment: Most of what I know about HTML and CSS I have learned from [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com). HTML Dog has [a page in its tutorial](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/layout/) about making a two column layout with a footer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try [this Dynamic Drive layout](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/) and its relatives (that I was pointed to via a similar question of mine).

Answer (score 48):

There is actually an even easier solution to this which i discovered not too long ago. Works well back to IE7. The #fluid div will slide up next to the fixed fix and take up the remaining space while maintaining great fluidity for all responsive sites.

http://jsfiddle.net/uEj55/1/

```
#fixed{
  width:150px;
  float:left;
}
#fluid{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the column heights to always be equal? See this demo, I would not like to see any red. http://jsfiddle.net/louiswalch/uEj55/92/

Comment: This solution also works great if you want the fixed column on the right and the fluid on the left.  Simply change the css for #fixed to float:right.

Comment: This is great- can you explain what overflow: hidden does in this context?

Comment: Louis W, Set both columns to: margin-bottom: -10000px; padding-bottom: 10000px; overflow: hidden;

Comment: I would love to know why overflow: hidden is necessary on this case too.

Comment: @GastónSánchez overflow:hidden is used to create a [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), which is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a Web page.

Answer (score 1):

The one I use is the faux-column layout hack, which includes no scripting.

Here's a tutorial that seems to be a simple explaination of the concept:
[dustinbrewer.com](http://dustinbrewer.com/using-faux-columns-for-same-column-height/)

Here's the original alistapart.com article that I learned from: [alistapart.com](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

Good luck!