# How do you implement a fixed left sidebar and fluid right content in CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I got headache how to make my fluid content will float to right.

1. left sidebar is fixed size.
2. right content is fluid size.

Here and [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HWMJc/) my `html` and `css`

How to make my `id="content"` will float on right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Layout  2-Column fixed-fluid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580195/css-layout-2-column-fixed-fluid)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set a margin and remove the float/width on #content, like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px;
}
#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 0 0 100px;
}
div {
    border:1px solid #333;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWMJc/1/

Comment: Awesome meder. So the width 100% is not important?

Comment: You don't need it in this case since you're setting a left margin.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually an even easier solution to this which i discovered not too long ago. Works well back to IE7. The #fluid div will slide up next to the fixed fix and take up the remaining space while maintaining great fluidity for all responsive sites. Dont need put a float or width on the fluid div at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/HWMJc/874/

```
#sidebar {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
}
#content {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: this is actually the better solution. Didn't know this when I was working front end two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should set it to be:

```
sidebar{ width:100px; float: left}
```

Answer (score -4):

Don't use 100% width on #content. 
70% works, but there is a small gap between the two elements. You can  adjust it to make it fit better though.

Comment: How about if we have different monitor sizes?

Comment: It should still adjust properly.