# Div layout with 3 columns: fixed - liquid - fixed

Tags: html, css, liquid-layout

I'm trying to build a 3 column layout that has one fixed column on the left, a fluid column in the middle and another fixed column on the right.

Anyone seen this?

There are similar problems here, but not the solution I was looking for.
[CSS Layout 2-Column fixed-fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580195/css-layout-2-column-fixed-fluid)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C13/

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-31-fixed-fluid-fixed/

Yes?

Comment: Sounds about right. My google skills seems to have deteriorated.

Answer (score 1):

Use fixed width and float to the appropriate side on the left and right columns. Then set the right and left margins of the fluid div to the width of the fixed divs. Fluid div should follow the fixed ones in the html.