# A fixed width block in a fluid layout

Tags: css, responsive-design

In a fluid layout I need in the same line, side by side, a fixed-width block and a fluid width block with a max width. When the window is resized, the fluid width block should resize being "pushed" by the fixed width block.

Here is what I came to achieve: http://cssdesk.com/gHvUB

But sadly the content expands outside its container .....

Anyone ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve your goal with the example you gave would be to

1. Add a right margin of 200px to the fluid box
2. Add a relative position of -200px to the fixed-width box.

   ```
   .line {
      ...
      position: relative;
    }
   .fluid {
      ...
      margin-right: 200px;
    }
   .fixed-width {
      ...
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      right: -200px;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

With css (and especially css3) there are going to be many different ways to achieve this.

Here a couple examples:

[example](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-22-fluid-fixed/)

[example](http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-box-model/1-column-fixed-1-column-fluid.html)

And here on the site:

[CSS Layout 2-Column fixed-fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580195/css-layout-2-column-fixed-fluid)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the easiest way is to set the container to overflow: auto. Then set both child containers to position: absolute. Since the container's position:relative they'll sit inside the parent. Then you need to set the parent's height to something. You can try min-height: (value). [I have a sample here.](http://cssdesk.com/HkwwV)

Hope this helps.