# Make a sidebar div a fixed width while the main content is fluid

Tags: html, css, layout

I need the main content of my website to be fluid between the left edge of the page and the sidebar. But I want the sidebar to remain fixed size.

I've seen some solutions that require the sidebar to be before the main content in the DOM, but in this case **the sidebar has to come after the main content in the HTML**.

Please see my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kK5Ly/

Right now the sidebar is floated left, but it's underneath the main content. I need it to sit beside the main content while keeping the main content fluid width.

Comment: and what if the height of main content and sidebar will be different, is it ok for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found to answer in this stack overflow question:

[CSS Layout 2-Column fixed-fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580195/css-layout-2-column-fixed-fluid?rq=1)

And this is the answer:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/

The CSS code is display to see how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

Try `display: table-cell` for the two containers – see http://jsfiddle.net/kK5Ly/9/

Comment: Usually fine, if you don’t need support for IE7.  http://caniuse.com/#search=table

Answer (score 1):

here I have done a little trick using `position: absolute`, maybe this is what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/kK5Ly/2/

Comment: Thanks Haynar, but there's a problem with this technique for me. Sometimes the sidebar might be longer than the container, which makes it sit on top of the footer. I tried to fix this via JS, but sometimes there will also be divs that expand in the main content. So it becomes very tricky.

Comment: @Owen in my site I've fixed that setting the height of main content and div to the maximum of both via JS

Comment: I mean the height of main content and sidebar

Comment: Thanks again, but I actually found a solution that works perfectly for my site, and requires no JS. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @haynar. I was trying to put the sidebar on the left and the main content on the right when I was testing it. Make sure that when you use that code not only do you add the `position:absolute;` to the sidebar div but you also set `margin-right:250px;` for the main content div.