# HTML Overflow Not Clean

Tags: html, css

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZGAK/)

I use some css:

```
#body { overflow-y:scroll; }
```

to make the content area scrollable, so you don't have to scroll the page.

My aim is to have a full height side bar at all times, so I figured that I have this content element `#body` have a scroll and it be fine. However, it makes the border really weird when scrolling data, the bottom border isn't just scrolling it's redrawn, how do I get past that? If someone could just help me tidy up the css and elements based on the information that would be great

Part 2: I want there to be two panels, the left fixed width and the right taking up the remainding width of the screen? how do I do this so that I can have `#body` take up `90%` of the second panels' width without having to set a fixed width with loads of left margin?

Thanks,

Comment: I think those should be two questions. And what is "really weird"? Here on my machine, lots of things overlap; is one of the effects of that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the #body element (might want to rename for clarity since theres already an html body element) is partially hidden under the sidebar.

If you give it `left:300px` then the scroll bar is no longer hidden but you are left with the issue of the right pane needing a width which will be determined by the size of the browser window.

Have a look at this: [CSS Layout 2-Column fixed-fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580195/css-layout-2-column-fixed-fluid)
which links to this article : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/  for ideas on how to do that.

Comment: this is close to what I want! will modify to get it exact, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

The bottom border is not being redrawn as far as I can see, you simply have `#container{border: 3px solid gray;}` on a higher element which is making the 'really weird' effect

**Note:** you have 2 elements with `id='container`. Ids should be unique and used only once per document

**Update:**
Here is a fiddle showing my tips in practice. I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/GZGAK/4/

Comment: it was only done quick, so there might be a few little basic errors, thanks for the input

Comment: They are not just typos - The multiple ids are causing the problem. See fiddle in my answer

Comment: Yup, I only edited your CSS for `#body` and `#container`. Changing the latter to `section#container` specifies that the CSS should *only* apply to the second `<section id='container'>` element, so it has the same effect as removing the duplicate id. You should, however also rename `<div id='container'>` in your html to avoid the duplicate.